# Getting an attribute of a directive from another directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have **two directives**, the first directive has an **attribute called layer-view** that is filled by a controller in the directive imapGrid would like to capture the value of this **attribute**.

## html

```
<ng-map mapid="mapid" layers-view="geo"></ng-map>
<imap-grid></imap-grid>
```

> ng.map.directive.js

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('ngMap', ngMap);

    function ngMap($q, $parse) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                layersView: '='
            },
            transclude: true,
            controller: function($scope) {
                this.getScope = function() {
                    return $scope;
                };
            },

            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            }
        };
    }

})();
```

> imap.grid.directive.js

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('imapGrid', imapGrid);

    function imapGrid($q, $parse) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: true,
            replace: false,
            templateUrl: 'src/templates/imapGrid/grid.html',
            require: '?^ngMap',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                var scope = ctrl.getScope();
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

I would like to have access to the contents of the **layer-view** attribute of the directive **imapGrid**

Comment: `<imap-grid>` is outside `<ng-map>`, so it's not really a child of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I see right now is that you're referring `require: '?^ngMap'` in your code.. But your html 
`<ng-map mapid="mapid" layers-view="geo"></ng-map>
<imap-grid></imap-grid>`
clearly tells that `ng-map` is not a father directive of `imap-grid`

So use  `require: '?ngMap'`to get ngMap as it is a sibling directive of imapGrid

Source: [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile](http://The%20issue%20I%20see%20right%20now%20is%20that%20you're%20referring%20%60require:%20'?%5EngMap'%60%20in%20your%20code..%20But%20your%20html%20%20%60%3Cng-map%20mapid=%22mapid%22%20layers-view=%22geo%22%3E%3C/ng-map%3E%20%3Cimap-grid%3E%3C/imap-grid%3E%60%20clearly%20tells%20that%20%60ng-map%60%20is%20not%20a%20father%20directive%20of%20%60imap-grid%60%20%20So%20use%20%20%60require:%20'?ngMap'%60%20%20Source:%20https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: I used require '?ngMap', but the ctrl is null

Comment: I thought to do this: `<imap-grid layers-view="geo"></imap-grid>`, the geo undergo changes will affect the two directive, but I do not know if it would be the best way

Comment: Since you have bound it as layersView: '=' , you can directly use it of course.. And so it doesn't matter if you get the value from the directive or the model it self :) (i.e. the one that you thought about)